# how to find the "true" entropy of std::random_device?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I want to check whether my implementation of `std::random_device`
has non-zero entropy (i.e. is non-deterministic), using `std::random_device::entropy()` function. However, according
to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device/entropy)

> "This function is not fully implemented in some standard libraries. 
>   For example, gcc and clang always return zero even though  the device
>   is non-deterministic. In comparison, Visual C++ always  returns 32,
>   and boost.random returns 10."

Is there any way of finding the real entropy? In particular, do modern
computers (MacBook Pro/iMac etc) have a non-deterministic source or randomness, like e.g. using heat dissipation monitors?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand - Ivy Bridge x86 processors provide with a random number which is at least save for cryptographic purposes.

Comment: There is the good old trick of generating a huge amount of random numbers, writing them to a file and compressing it with gzip or similar.  Then compare the compression ratio with that of a sample obtained from a known high-enropy source (such as `/dev/random`) and a known low-entropy source (such as 1, 2, 3, …).

Comment: I just did this and found no difference between `std::random_device` and `/dev/urandom` (which is no surprise since GCC's libstdc++ implements the former in terms of the latter).  *However*, I *also* see no difference for an unseeded `std::rand()` (from `cstdlib`) and that indicates that the benchmark is not tough enough.

Comment: @5gon12eder thanks for the idea and for trying it. Yes, it is not so surprising, as distinguishing between a good PRNG and a RNG is quite a tricky business. A zip algorithm can probably be useful provided that it achieves the compression limit (i.e. the Shannon entropy of the source), but that's not really the case in reality.

Comment: Have you considered trying a randomness benchmark such as [TestU01](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestU01) or [diehard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests)?

Comment: Ummm I think this is the best answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator#Problems It basically covers everything: good estimation is impossible, even hardware can silently fail and advises to use performance tests. I don't think there will a better answer but doesn't seem nice just to rewrite it.

Comment: OS X uses the Yarrow algorithm to provide data via /dev/urandom, which is what is used by default in `std::random_device` on OS X's implementation. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42952/how-can-i-measure-and-increase-entropy-on-mac-os-x

Comment: @luk32 and bames53 then I wonder why `std` provided the function, perhaps they though of allowing any device (including quantum number generators which have non-zero entropy). Although the thing that bothers me is why the query to `entropy` is unreliable? If the implementation uses some kind of thermal noise implementation, then it should at least provide a lower bound.

Comment: This was a good question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend you the lecture of this article.

[Myths about /dev/urandom](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/)

§ 26.5.6

> A random_device uniform random number generator produces non-deterministic random numbers.
>
> If implementation limitations prevent generating non-deterministic random numbers, the implementation may employ a random number engine.

So basically it will try to use the internal system "true" random number generator, in linux /dev/{u}random o windows RltGenRandom.

A different point is you don't trust those sources of randomness because they depend on internal noise or are close implementations.

Additionally is how do you meassure the quality of entropy, as you know that is one of the biggest problem trying to find good rng generators.

One estimation could be extremely good and other estimation could report not so good entropy.

### [Entropy Estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_estimation)

> In various science/engineering applications, such as independent
> component analysis, image analysis, genetic analysis, speech
> recognition, manifold learning, and time delay estimation it is useful
> to estimate the differential entropy of a system or process, given
> some observations.

As it sais, you must rely on final observations, and those can be wrong.

I you think the internal rng is not good enough, you can always try to buy hardware devices for that purpose. This [list on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hardware_random_number_generators) has a list of vendors, you can check on the internet reviews about them.

### Performance

One point you must consider is the performance within your application using real random number generators. One common technique is to use as seed in a mersenne twister a number obtained using /dev/random.

If the user can't access your system physically, you will need to balance reliability with availability, a system with security holes is as bad as one doesn't work, at the end you must have your important data encrypted.

Edit 1: As suggestion I have moved the article at the top of my comment, is a good read. Thanks for the hint :-).

Answer (score 6):

All the standard gives you is what you've already seen. You would need to know something about how a given standard library implements `random_device` in order to answer this question. For example, in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4, `random_device` forwards to [`rand_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxtz2fa8.aspx) which forwards to [`RtlGenRandom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387694.aspx), which may actually be (always?) a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator depending on your Windows version and the hardware available.

If you don't trust the platform to provide a good source of entropy, then you should use your own cryptographically secure PRNG, such as one based on AES. That said, platform vendors have strong incentives for their random numbers to actually be random, and embedding the PRNG into your app means that the PRNG can't be updated as easily in the event it is found to be insecure. Only you can decide on that tradeoff for yourself :)

Comment: but again you see I have 0% trust in how Microsoft implements some internal function that generates randomness, as this is one of the most important parts in a key-exchange protocol. However, it seems indeed that standard C++ doesn't provide/enforce a standard way.

Comment: @vsoftco: Then `random_device`, which is specified as an implementation defined source of randomness, is not for you :)

Comment: yeah, that's exactly the side issue, how much can I "trust" `random_device`. I did tests on it and indeed "seems" random, but I wouldn't bet my life on it on serious crypto applications.

Comment: @vsoftco: Yeah, if you don't trust the platform, you can't rely on it. It's up to the implementer to provide the random source. Even hardware answers like `rdrand` leave you trusting the hardware to be actually random.

Comment: @vsoftco Steven T. Lavavej (maintainer for Microsoft's C++ Standard Library implementation) said that they guarantee it being cryptographically secure in his talk [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) (18min mark) so the "always?" in the answer can probably be removed. As for other implementations check the documentation. And if you don't trust the implementer you got no way than implementing it yourself... even if the standard mandated a proper way to distinguish you'd still have to trust them to implement it correctly.

Comment: @Raphael A cryptographically secure PRNG is still cryptographically secure. But it's not nondeterministic. As I mentioned, it eventually ends up in `RtlGenRandom`.

Answer (score 3):

Entropy is just one measure of RNG quality (and true, exact entropy is impossible to measure). For a practical and reasonably-accurate measurement of your `std::random_device`'s random number quality, consider using a standard *randomness test suite* such as [TestU01](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestU01), [diehard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests), or its successor [dieharder](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php). These run a battery of statistical tests designed to stress your RNG, ensuring it produces statistically random data.

Note that statistical randomness by itself does not certify that the RNG is suitable for cryptographic applications.

---

Many modern computers have easily-accessible sources of hardware randomness, namely the analog-to-digital converters found in the audio input, camera, and various sensors. These exhibit low-level thermal or electrical noise which can be exploited to produce high-quality random data. However, no OS that I know of actually uses these sensors to supply their system random-number sources (such as `/dev/[u]random`), since the bitrate of such physical random number sources tends to be very low.

Instead, OS-provided random number sources tend to be seeded by hardware counters and events, such as page faults, device driver events, and other sources of unpredictability. In theory, these events might be fully predictable given the precise hardware state (since they aren't based on e.g. quantum or thermal noise), but in practice they are sufficiently unpredictable that they produce good random data.

Comment: That's why I was asking for the entropy. Entropy by itself is a certified measure of randomness in crypto application, as you can distill true randomness out of sources of non-zero entropy. Anyway, thanks for the links, will take a look. PS: I had the feeling that `/dev/random` in UNIX-like systems use thermal noise (even if the bitrate is low)

Comment: @vsoftco: the trouble is that measuring "true" entropy is basically impossible (it would require knowing the full physical process underlying your RNG source). Instead, statistical tests serve as a useful substitute.

Comment: seems reasonable, and now if I think a bit more it is impossible for a C++ standard to guarantee true randomness as it's model is based on some abstract deterministic turing-machine-like device.

Answer (score 1):

Entropy as a scientific term is misused when describing random numbers. Complexity might be a better term.  Entropy in physics is defined as the logarithm of the number of available quantum states (not useful in RNG), and entropy in information theory is defined by the Shannon entropy, but that is geared towards the other extreme - how to put as much information into a noisy bit stream, not how to minimize the information.

For example, the digits of Pi look random, but the actual entropy of the digits is zero once you know that they derive from Pi. Increasing "Entropy" in RNG is basically a question of making the source of the numbers as obscure as possible.

Comment: Thanks, I am quite aware of what entropy means though :) I truly mean here the Shannon entropy of the source.